# DataGrid summing values incorrectly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am summing the value of a column in a DataGrid that is updated every time another DataGrid is updated. Say, user selects value in DataGrid1 it adds that data to DataGrid. That part is working wonderfully. I need to sum one of the columns so it gives me a total. This is the code I came up with, which fires under GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged event.

```
        For Each GridViewRow In GridView2.Rows


            Sum = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells(3).Text)
            Total = Sum + Total
            lblTotal.Text = Total.ToString

        Next
```

Now the problem comes from this. If I have rwo values, of say... 2.00, the sum is ok. It'll give me 4. But if I add another Item, say Item2, which has a value of 2.30 it gives me a total of 4.60.  If I first add the 2.30 item and then add the 2 item it gives me a value of 4. What the heck is going on and how can such a simple math go wrong :P! Am I missing something? rounding? Need to parse something?

Full code ahead

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged


    Dim row = GridView1.SelectedRow
    If Not row Is Nothing AndAlso IsNumeric(row.Cells(3).Text) Then
        Dim Price As Double = CDbl(row.Cells(3).Text)
        Dim Name As String = CStr(row.Cells(2).Text)
        lblCart.Visible = True
        Dim InfoTotal As String = "$" & "    " & Precio & "      " & Nombre


        Dim Total As Double

        If GridView2.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            '  dt = New DataTable()
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name", GetType(System.String)))
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Price", GetType(System.String)))
        Else
            dt = DirectCast(Session("DataTable"), DataTable)
        End If

        Dim Sum As Double
        Dim dr1 As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        dr1(0) = Name.ToString
        dr1(1) = CDbl(Price.ToString)
        dt.Rows.Add(dr1)
        GridView2.DataSource = dt
        GridView2.DataBind()
        Session("DataTable") = dt

        For Each GridViewRow In GridView2.Rows
            Sum = CDbl(row.Cells(3).Text)
            Total += Sum
        Next

        lblTotal.Text = Total.ToString
        ListBox1.Items.Add(CStr(InfoTotal))

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Its a Double.  `Dim Total As Double`

Comment: Have you tried debug-stepping through it to read Total each time it's converted to a string?  Is lblTotal using automatic string formatting of some kind?  `StringFormat="{0:N0}"` perhaps?

Comment: I originally had it set to "{0:c}" but it was causing errors because of the $ sign. It's set to {0:f2} so it rounds up and shows at least two 0s since its supposed to be a currency. I also left it "unchanged" to no avail. I did use breakpoints to see where the problem was but the program is, supposedly, executing well. It just doesn't add up as it should and its just so puzzling. I tried to save the value in a session since its an ASP page and no go either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code was fine... it was something simple. I added a session and changed Rows to Column. Code for that area:

```
 Dim Total As Double
    Dim Sum As Double
    Total = Session("Total")



    For Each GridViewRow In GridView2.Columns

        Sum = CDbl(row.Cells(3).Text)
        Total = CDbl(Total + Sum)
        Session("Total") = Total

    Next

    lblTotal.Text = Total.ToString
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are missing some additional code in there where you are adding the value twice - please post your full code. Below accomplishes what you are doing with (ever so slightly) less code - also, no point updating the label until the `for` has finished.

```
For Each GridViewRow In GridView2.Rows
                Sum = CDbl(row.Cells(3).Text)
                Total += Sum
            Next

lblTotal.Text = Total.ToString
```